# Check in PHP if Select Exists returned 1

Tags: php, mysql

I know that in SQL if I wrote

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM userdata WHERE user_id=2);
```

SQL returned a 1 if it managed to select and a 0 if not.

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM userdata WHERE user_id=2) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              1 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

How would I check this in a PHP? I am using MySQLi. I want the code to look something like this…

```
    $selectbruh = SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM userdata WHERE user_id=2);

    if(select returned 1){
        //Do this
    }else if(returned 0){
        //Do this
    }else{
        //Explode into smithereens
    }
```

Comment: You're mssing a lot of code here. Can you share what you have *actually* tried?

Comment: Plus, which MySQL API are you using to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other?

Comment: If you don't share what you're actually trying it would be impossible for us to guess where to start @SnamakoolLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are confused because you've taken a… well… *unorthodox* approach, both with your SQL and with posting your code. You've said that you're using MySQLi, so here is the answer you're looking for:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT 1 FROM userdata WHERE user_id = 2;');

if ($query->num_rows) {
    echo "Query returned 1\n";
} else {
    echo "Query returned 0\n";
}
```

It looks to me like you're trying to validate whether a user ID exists or not, in which case the results are either "exists" (1) or "doesn't exist" (0). There is no room for `//Explode into smithereens`, which I believe is a good thing :)

Comment: HAHA Thanks, I didnt realise it would be soo simple!

Comment: Ok. So people have convinced me to use PDO instad of mysqli so how I do the same in PDO.

Comment: Please ask new questions as new questions, otherwise they are not discoverable for others.

Comment: I cant ask another question. I have to wait 2 days or something

Comment: Well, OK. I don't like answering like this, but I also don't want to leave you hanging. So, you want something like this: `$query = $db->query('SELECT 1 FROM userdata WHERE user_id = 2;'); if ($query->fetchColumn()) { echo "Query returned 1\n"; } else { echo "Query returned 0\n"; }`